# Project Euler no. 17 - Streamlining Python

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm very new to programming and am admittedly embarrassed sharing my code for critique. This code works and produces the correct answer to the following problem (https://projecteuler.net/problem=17), but I was hoping I could get some critique on how to make it less ugly and more streamlined, or even approach the problem from a totally new angle so I can better learn from this solution. Thanks much for any help!

```
# the final list that holds the string lengths
addList = [] 

# dictionary holding integer:corresponding word pairs
numbersDict = { 
0:"zero",
1:"one",
2:"two",
3:"three",
4:"four",
5:"five",
6:"six",
7:"seven",
8:"eight",
9:"nine",
10:"ten",
11:"eleven",
12:"twelve",
13:"thirteen",
14:"fourteen",
15:"fifteen",
16:"sixteen",
17:"seventeen",
18:"eighteen",
19:"nineteen",
20:"twenty",
30:"thirty",
40:"forty",
50:"fifty",
60:"sixty",
70:"seventy",
80:"eighty",
90:"ninety"
}

### There has to be an easier way to do all this below ###

def numberLetters(num):

    letters = ""

    if 0 < num <= 20:
        letters += numbersDict[num]

    if 21 <= num <= 99:
        a,b = divmod(num, 10)
        if b == 0:
            letters += numbersDict[a*10]
        else:
            letters += numbersDict[a*10] + numbersDict[b]

    if 100 <= num <= 999:
        if num % 100 == 0:
            letters += numbersDict[int(num / 100)] + "hundred"
        else:
            digit = int(num / 100)
            num = num - digit * 100
            if 0 < num <= 20:
                letters += numbersDict[digit] + "hundredand" + numbersDict[num]
            if 21 <= num <= 99:
                a,b = divmod(num, 10)
                if b == 0:
                    letters += numbersDict[digit] + "hundredand" + numbersDict[a*10]
                else:
                    letters += numbersDict[digit] + "hundredand" + numbersDict[a*10] + numbersDict[b]
    if num == 1000:
        letters += "onethousand"

    return letters

for i in range(1,1001):
    addList.append(len(numberLetters(i)))
print(sum(addList))
```

Comment: If you want a critique of working code post it on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code :

```
words = [
(1,   'one'      ,''   ),
(2,   'two'      ,''   ),
(3,   'three'    ,''   ),
(4,   'four'     ,''   ),
(5,   'five'     ,''   ),
(6,   'six'      ,''   ),
(7,   'seven'    ,''   ),
(8,   'eight'    ,''   ),
(9,   'nine'     ,''   ),
(10,  'ten'      ,''   ),
(11,  'eleven'   ,''   ),
(12,  'twelve'   ,''   ),
(13,  'thirteen' ,''   ),
(14,  'fourteen' ,''   ),
(15,  'fifteen'  ,''   ),
(16,  'sixteen'  ,''   ),
(17,  'seventeen',''   ),
(18,  'eighteen' ,''   ),
(19,  'nineteen' ,''   ),
(20,  'twenty'   ,''   ),
(30,  'thirty'   ,''   ),
(40,  'forty'    ,''   ),
(50,  'fifty'    ,''   ),
(60,  'sixty'    ,''   ),
(70,  'seventy'  ,''   ),
(80,  'eighty'   ,''   ),
(90,  'ninety'   ,''   ),
(100, 'hundred'  ,'and'),
]
words.reverse()

def spell(n, i=0):
    global words
    word = ""
    while n > 0:
        for num in words[i:]:
            if num[0] <= n:
                div = n // num[0]
                n = n % num[0]
                if num[2]: word+=' '+spell(div,i)
                word+=' '+num[1]
                if num[2] and n: word+=' '+num[2]
                break
    return word[1:]

count = lambda s: sum(1 for i in s if i!=' ')
print(sum(count(spell(n)) for n in range(1001)))
```

Note that I use a recursive function, and that I added the facultative parameter 'i' to spell that records the last index used in words and thus spares some iterations in the `for num in words` loop (not very useful indeed, but it costed only 6 characters ^^). Then, I used a superfluous **lambda function** to make the `count` function, because the name of a function is some sort of comment.
Finally, I used the sum function over the **generator expression** `count(spell(n)) for n in range(1001)`.
The code can be even shorter if you delete all the occurrences of `' '+` and replace count with len, but with this code you have a correct `spell` function.

If you did not understand a term in bold, then you should read a book about Python 3.

If you want to spare some time, you can even memoize the spell function, or make a count(spell()) function that you memoize (because letter count integers are lighter than strings).

Answer (score 0):

You can use if/elif

```
if 0 < num <= 20:
    letters += numbersDict[num]

elif 21 <= num <= 99:
```

You can also define functions that do anything that repeats.  I would also just do all the calculations upfront regardless of it's range.  so for example

```
digit = int(num / 100)
```

will end up with digit=0 for num=55, but that's okay, you can handle that and skip it.

Think about what would happen if you had to write the code to a million.  What would seem repetitive?  Pull that code out and make more functions.